# What is O in binomial distribution entropy?

Tags: binomial-distribution, entropy

I have searched everywhere but can't find an answer. What is "O" refers to in this equation?

$${\frac {1}{2}}\log _{2}\left(2\pi enp(1-p)\right)+O\left({\frac {1}{n}}\right)$$

Comment: I suppose it denotes the *big Oh* notation, from asymptotic analysis: a function of $n$ which is $\le C\cdot \frac1n$ for a constant $C$ when $n$ is large enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the "big Oh" notation described in this wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).  In your case it means an approximation error of size no worse then $\pm C/n$, for some unstated constant $C$.

More precisely, such an estimate holds for all sufficiently large $n$.  Your example is derived from Stirling's approximation to $\log n!$; this approximation has only limited  accuracy for small $n$ but better and better accuracy for big $n$.

Comment: So according to @Bernard's comment, if n is small, we can ignore this part for entropy calculation, right?

Comment: No.  You can ignore the big O part when $n$ is very large.  For small $n$ those terms could be important.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Of course you are right; I was mixed up.  I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n) = O\left(\frac 1 n \right)$ then $|f(n)| \le \frac M n$ for all $n \ge n_0$, for some positive constant $M$ and $n_0$.